# How to avoid Child Property REQUIRED DataAnnotation during Parent Model CRUD

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, data-annotations

Please help me learn and correct my code...

**Goal:**

1. During City CRUD: the only required property is Name, ZipCode can be null
2. When adding Contact.ContactAddresses, the only required property is Line1, user can leave City as null/empty
3. A Contact (*required with Name*) can have many contact addresses (*with only ContactAddress.Line1 is filled while ContactAddress.CityId and ContactAddress.City can be null/empty*)

**Problem:**

When trying to **UPDATE a contact** containing a contact address that has **a NULL City property**, an error is thrown stating something like "**City: Name field is required and must not be empty.**".

I believe that when trying to update my contact that contains a NULL ContactAddress.CityId, the **ContactAddress.City.Name throws the DataAnnotation error**.

**Question:**

How do I use the **Required** DataAnnotation in City.Name during CRUD of City, but allow City (*and consequently City.Name*) to be NULL during CRUD of Contact's Contact.ContactAddresses?

Please see model code below:

```
public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name field is required and must not be empty.")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Name must be 3-50 characters long.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ContactAddress> ContactAddresses { get; set; }
}

public class ContactAddress
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(70, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "AddressLine must be 3-70 characters long.")]
    public string AddressLine { get; set; }

    public int? CityId { get; set; }
    public City City { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name field is required and must not be empty.")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Name must be 3-50 characters long.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Name must be 3-10 characters long.")]
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Make Sure that the ContactAddress.City is also null or it should not be attached as entity

Comment: Thank you sir Shantanu! Checking and making sure that the ContactAddress.City is null actually solved the problem!

Comment: @GAC I understand calling people sir is a thing, but don't assume gender. That's never good.

Comment:  You are absolutely correct @10Rep..I'll make sure to stop doing it! Thank you for calling my attention.